# What makes Space Adaptation Syndrome worse?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, health, space-sickness

Are there any particular movements or activities that exacerbate SAS, space sickness?

Comment: slightly related [Is the vestibular system ever useful in spaceflight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36208/12102)

Comment: [Running around in circles](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34569/12102) perhaps? Or [artificial gravity](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9575/12102)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there are probably several body motions that can exacerbate SAS.

Anecdotally, I can tell you that it was well understood by Shuttle flight crew that the act of doffing the [Advanced Crew Escape Suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Crew_Escape_Suit) (ACES) (which usually occurred within a few hours of orbital insertion) was considered especially provocative with respect to the SAS problem.  This was primarily due to the act of pulling one's head through the snugly fitting rubber membrane neck dam, a process some referred to as akin to being "birthed all over again."

Also, during that vulnerable first day on orbit, if one was feeling a bit green, she was well advised to maintain cabin orientations that felt "normal" (i.e. no "upside down" body attitudes).

Of course, activities that might make one a bit queasy on Earth (i.e. administering injections, swallowing toothpaste, etc.) were best avoided for those first few hours, if possible.

Comment: Swallowing... Toothpaste? Ew...